# Specify node version for eslint

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I'm using eslint for a Node.js application. I'm running node version v10.6.0, but when I run `eslint` in the root directory of my project, I get error messages like the following:

```
The 'URL' is not supported until Node.js 10.0.0. The configured version range is '>=6.0.0'
```

My `.eslintrc.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:node/recommended",
  ],
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
}
```

and my `package.json` contains:

```
"engine": {
    "node": ">=10.6.0"
}
```

How can I tell eslint that I'm using a newer node version? I'm using eslint v5.2.0.

Comment: Are you using one of Jetbrain IDE's?! if so you have to configure node version in IDE's settings

Comment: You can specify Ecma version. Have a look at [this](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)

Comment: @kgangadhar I tried specifying the `ecmaVersion` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `engine` property in the `package.json` file is incorrect and should be `engines` instead. This is the property that eslint uses to determine the node version.

Comment: Adding `engines` seems to have no affect on the ESLint server in VSCode. Could you reference your source?

Answer (score 2):

You must use engines not engine as bellow and it solves your issue.

```
engines:{
    "node": ">=10.6.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
"node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax": ["error", {
    "version": ">=8.0.0",
    "ignores": []
}]
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

remove "plugin:node/recommended", from your .eslintrc.json file , i was facing the same issue after removing it, my code is working fine .