# How to configure eslint to support ecmascript included in latest node lts

Tags: node.js, default, eslint, lts

eslint file has many options, but if I want to support all the features supported in node 10.x LTS for instance, how can I do that?

Comment: I use [standard](https://standardjs.com/) it enforces it's own rules which means there's no configuration. So far I have not seen it act weird with Node 10

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626292/specify-node-version-for-eslint